# Consulta como editar una tableyout

Tags: java

Muy buenas estimada comunidad y esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, estoy trabajando con mi primer tablelayout dentro del primer fargment que realizo, el insertar y al mostrar los datos de la tabla tambien funcionan, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que una al hacer click en cualquier fila este sea editado a sus respectivas cajas de texto, este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
public class mano extends Fragment {

EditText txtitem2,txtdetalle,txtvalor,txtid,g,h,i,j,txtvalor1,colFilas,colDetalle,colValor;
Button btn_buscar1,cmdingresar,cmdsuma,cmdmodificar;
TableLayout tbldatos,tbldatos1;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Detalle","Valor"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableRow tableRow;
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

public mano() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mano, container, false);
    txtitem2 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem2);
    String aa = "1";
    txtitem2.setText(aa);
    txtdetalle = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdetalle);
    txtvalor = view.findViewById(R.id.txtvalor);
    txtid = view.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    g = view.findViewById(R.id.g);
    g.setText("");
    h = view.findViewById(R.id.h);
    i = view.findViewById(R.id.i);
    String ab = "0";
    i.setText(ab);
    j = view.findViewById(R.id.j);
    String ac = "0";
    j.setText(ac);
    txtvalor1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtvalor1);
    tbldatos = view.findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);
    tbldatos1 = view.findViewById(R.id.tbldatos1);
    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    btn_buscar1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar1);
    cmdingresar = view.findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    cmdsuma = view.findViewById(R.id.cmdsuma);
    cmdsuma.setEnabled(false);
    cmdmodificar = view.findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    cmdmodificar.setEnabled(false);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    recupero();

    btn_buscar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buscar();
        }
    });
```

al hacer click en este botón, se dirige al private en el cual busca los datos y los muestra en el tabla, y posteriormente dentro de esta misma realice el editar los datos hay mismo:

```
private void buscar(){
    cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
    cmdmodificar.setEnabled(true);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    String url = "http://192.168.1.90/gestion/buscar_presupuesto3.php?Patente_Vehiculo=" + g.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
            tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
            tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
            tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                final View[] registro = new View[jsonArray.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View fila = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla3, null, false);
                    colFilas = fila.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colDetalle = fila.findViewById(R.id.colDetalle);
                    colValor = fila.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colDetalle.setText(jsonObject.getString("Mano_Mobra"));
                    colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_Mobra"));
                    fila.setTag(id); // Guardar el valor del ID en el tag de la vista fila
                    tbldatos.addView(fila);
                    registro[i] = fila;
                    final int index = i;
                    mostrardatos();

                    // Agregar el listener de clic a la fila
                    fila.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Obtener los datos de la fila seleccionada
                            String colFilasText = colFilas.getText().toString();
                            String colDetalleText = colDetalle.getText().toString();
                            String colValorText = colValor.getText().toString();

                            // Asignar los datos a los EditText correspondientes
                            txtitem2.setText(colFilasText);
                            txtdetalle.setText(colDetalleText);
                            txtvalor.setText(colValorText);

                            // Obtener el valor del ID guardado en el tag de la vista fila
                            String id = fila.getTag().toString();

                            // Asignar el valor del ID al TextView txtid
                            txtid.setText(id);
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

ojala que me puedan asesorar y ayudar, ya que en netbeans con java hacia lo mismo editaba la fila o eliminaba la fila, y creo que debe pasar lo mismo acá en android, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, mira la descripción de la etiqueta que usas si no estás seguro de su uso. [tag:android-studio] es para problemas con el IDE. Diría que tu pregunta iría mejor en [tag:java] + [tag:android] y quizás alguna etiqueta relacionada con el tipo de layout. Si tuviera otras etiquetas le quitaría la que menciono, pero dado que no, dejo este comentario. Recuerda que las etiquetas son utilizadas por quienes responden para _filtrar_ de acuerdo a su expertís, y también para organizar la información del sitio. Encontrarás más información en [ask].

Comment: @jachguate master muchas gracias, pero como lo estoy realizando a través de android-studio pensaba que alguien podría asesorarme en esta comunidad, ahora mi consulta como lo hago para subirla de nuevo o debo realizarla desde foja cero de nuevo, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Solo daoe clic en [Edit] para hacer los cambios. Te invito a hacer el [tour] si has olvidado como funciona SO. Un saludo.